# Is there a way to check what version of Karate I have?

Tags: karate

I am going to attempt to update my version of Karate this week and I was just wondering if there is a way to verify the current version I am using. I'd like to know so that I can confirm that I have the new version once installed but also I'd like to know so that on the off chance I need to revert, I'll be able to verify that the older version is back after reverting (if that's even possible).

Answer (score 0):

When you run a test you should see something like this in the log:

```
23:36:06.578 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - Karate version: 1.1.0
```

or

```
HTML report: (paste into browser to view) | Karate version: 1.1.0
file:///some/path/target/karate-reports/karate-summary.html
===================================================================
```